# SignalR WinAuth does not Work

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, iis, signalr

I have a problem in SignalR connection with Win Auth. When I enable anonymous in IIS Authorize settings, it works but sometimes it gives HTTP 403 Forbidden error. After I researched, I found that I need to disable Anonymous Connections. But when disable and enable the windowsAuth in IIS then there is always HTTP 401.2 UnAuthorized error. How I can connect with WinAuth? For my project I need to use WinAuth.

Not1 : I am using Silverlight 5.

Not2 : I have already tried possible solutions on StackOverflow but none of them worked.

So why cant I use WinAuth? It is enabled everywhere in config files, in IIS settings as well as in my web.config.

I spent 2 days but still I could not find a solution. If you need more information just write a comment. I am not sure what else information I can share. I dont want to put here lots of unnecessary texts.

EDIT:
When I use this code, i.e if I enter the username and password explicitly then it works. Internet Explorer first uses Anonymous Authentication and then it fails then it uses NetworkCredentials directly. This is the code

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection("URL");
hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HUBNAME");
hubConnection.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ID", "PASSWORD");
```

(The ones with capital letters are specific to my app.)

So how can I get Windows Credentials for my Silverlight App? DefaultCredentials does not work for silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added authorization to your hub?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] 
public class AdminAuthHub : Hub 
{ 
}
```

Comment: I added a new project to solution and I turned off WinAuth and turned on Anonymous authentication for this poject only (since I cant chage the features of the other projects in the solution). I cant try right now but definitely I will give a try. Thanks.